# Simplex - Help with a proof

Tags: proof-verification, convex-analysis, simplex

I am trying to prove the following (basic) claim about simplex. If you check my proof and help me with the part where I stuck, I would appreciate it very much.

Let $X$ be a finite set and define $\Delta(X)=\left\{\mu:X\to[0,1]\mid\sum_{x\in X} \mu(x)=1 \right\}$. Show that $\Delta(X)$ is non-empty, convex and compact.

My proof for the first two is the following: Suppose $X=\left\{x_1,\dots,x_n\right\}$ finite then $\mu(x)=1/n$ is in $\Delta(X)$ so it is non-empty. For $X=\emptyset$, $\mu(\emptyset)=1$ will work.

For convexity, let $\mu,\mu^{\prime}\in\Delta(X)$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$. Define $\bar{\mu }=\lambda\mu+(1-\lambda)\mu^{\prime}$. Since $0\leq\lambda\mu(x)\leq \lambda$ and $0\leq(1-\lambda)\mu^{\prime}(x)\leq(1-\lambda)$, we have $0\leq\bar{\mu}(x)\leq 1$. Similar argument shows $\sum_{x\in X}\bar{\mu}(x)=1$.

I couldn't figure out how to proceed for compactness. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your statement about the empty set is a bit shaky. When $X$ is empty, the function $\mu$ would have to be a triple $(\emptyset, \mathbb R, Q)$, where $Q$ is a subset of $\emptyset \times \mathbb R$ having the usual "function" properties...and then only such subset is the empty set. But for that function, the required sum is not 1. (Yeah, this is pedantic nonsense about functions defined on the empty set, but I happen, in my own way, to think it matters). Even ignoring the summation question, the notation $\mu(\emptyset)$ is not defined.

For compactness, you have to decide what topology you're putting on the space of functions.

Since $X$ is finite -- let's say it has $n$ elements -- the set of maps from $X$ to $\mathbb R$ looks a lot like $\mathbb R^n$. Compactness these is the same as "closed and bounded," by the Heine-Borel theorem. "Bounded" for $\Delta$ is easy: the set lies entirely in the unit cube in $\mathbb R^n$. What about "closed"? Suppose that $h$ is in the complement of $\Delta$. Then $h$ is a function on $X$ with one of two properties:

1. The sum of $h$'s values is $K \ne 1$, or
2. One of $h$'s value is outside the interval $[0, 1]$. I'll consider the case where the value is $K > 1$.

In each case, taking a ball of radius $\frac{K-1}/2$ around $h$, we find that every element of that ball also has property 1 or 2 (depending on which one held for $h$), so the entire ball is in the complement. Hence the complement of $\Delta$ is open, so $\Delta$ is closed.

(You still have to do the $K < 0$ case for condition 2, but I suspect that you can handle that.)

Comment: The question is not mentioning topology or metric space. So, I hesitate to put any more structure (topology or metric) on this space. For empty set, can we say the claim is vacuously true?

Comment: If the problem specifies no topology, then "compact" doesn't make sense. But the topology I've suggested in my expanded answer is certainly a reasonable one. As for the empty set, I have no idea what answer was intended.

Comment: Topology surely matters. If we place, say, the discrete topology on the space of functions from $X$ to $\mathbb R$, then only finite sets will be compact; if we use the topology I've described, then $\Delta$ will be compact. Anyhow, I don't think I can give any more insight here.